# Is there a way to script Microsoft Word to save all open documents automatically?

Tags: ms-word, autosave

My father can't seem to shutdown his computer, ever, so I'm using Task Scheduler to have it automatically power off every night. Thing is, he also can't seem to save his documents, so I need to make sure every open document has it's changes saved when it shuts down. Is it possible to do this using AutoHotkey, VBA, or with some MS Word feature I'm not aware of?

I'm aware of the AutoRecover feature. But, as I understand it, that just saves a copy in another folder that gets thrown away when the document is opened again. It's not as reliable as a manual save.

Any help on this is appreciated. It physically hurts to watch tech-illiterates abuse their PCs.

Comment: There is a simple solution exists for the problem since computers existed. Save button. IMHO if a person can open word and write some stuff he/she should be able to click save before he gets away from PC. If this is not possible I would suggest Onenote. It does save everything you tipped.

Comment: @haltunbay Normally, I would agree with you, but I know what'll happen is I'll tell him he needs to save, he won't, and I'll be blamed for his document loss when his PC powers off.